# How can i block updates for specific application?

Tags: updates, update-manager, thunderbird

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

I want keep my system updated but i don't want that a specific application is updated! In my case Thunderbird.
I don't want to uncheck every time proposed updates for Thunderbird.
How can i add an exception in the update-manager?

Comment: I found a partial answer by myself: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Synaptic But, what about security updates? If the package is blocked, i don't have security updates for currently version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes but you will need synaptic installed

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Then open synaptic and search for the package you want to lock and go 'Package>Lock Version'

Comment: But i have the problem explained in my comment.

Comment: As far as i can see this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> Update Manager > setting (software sources directly from Dash) >
>   updates

and then check just the security updates, the other updates will be manual.

Comment: Sorry but i don't want disable all updates and do them manually. Only for some applications. Thanks for answer.